# Trying to click the next button using Selenium python, but it is giving me ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website https://www.hcafloridahealthcare.com/physicians and you have to type in florida into the search bar. Once it get to the page, I want to scrape each physician's information. However, when I want to go to the next page, it give me an `ElementClickInterceptedException` error. The code I used was:

```py
nextButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label = 'go to next page']")

nextButton.click()
```

I just don't know how to click on the next button.

Answer (score 0):

Exception says, selenium not able to interact with target element https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementClickInterceptedException.html

just try different ways

- if element is not in visible screen, then scroll upto element and click
- try move to element and click on it
- try waits
- try javascript executor

In this, navigation bar is bottom of page, expecting, scroll to that element and click will work